# Perl: how to check dialup interface is up or down?

Tags: perl, networking, interface, dial-up

How can I check with the Perl independently from the operation system whether the specified local dial-up interface is up or down?

Answer (score -1):

Just use something like

$result1=`ifconfig -a`;  # (or ipconfig /all in windows),

then perform a regexp match on the result to look for that particular interface name and its status (or the presence of an ip addresss).

In linux, the interface name should be ppp0 .

Test the ifconfig/ipconfig outputs first with that interface up/down/absent to make sure you take all cases into account.